# How to implement argmax with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp, reduction

I am trying to implement a argmax with OpenMP. If short, I have a function that computes a floating point value:

```
double toOptimize(int val);
```

I can get the integer maximizing the value with:

```
double best = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(max: best)
for(int i = 2 ; i < MAX ; ++i)
{
    double v = toOptimize(i);
    if(v > best) best = v;
}
```

Now, how can I get the value `i` corresponding to the maximum?

**Edit:**

I am trying this, but would like to make sure it is valid:

```
double best_value = 0;
int best_arg = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
{
  double local_best = 0;
   int ba = 0;
#pragma omp for reduction(max: best_value)
  for(size_t n = 2 ; n <= MAX ; ++n)
  {
    double v = toOptimize(n);
    if(v > best_value)
    {
      best_value = v;
      local_best = v;
      bn = n;
    }
  }
#pragma omp barrier
#pragma omp critical
  {
    if(local_best == best_value)
      best_arg = bn;
  }
}
```

And in the end, I should have `best_arg` the argmax of `toOptimize`.

Comment: There is no need for any barrier explicit or implicit.  Remove the barrier and add `nowait` to the parallel loop.  That way if one thread finishes the loop while the others are still working it can enter the critical section right away and the other threads can keep doing their work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is completely standard conformant. Anyhow, if you are willing to add a bit of syntactic sugar, you may try something like the following:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

double toOptimize(int arg) {
  return arg * (arg%100);
}

class MaximumEntryPair {
public:

  MaximumEntryPair(size_t index = 0, double value = 0.0) : index_(index), value_(value){}

  void update(size_t arg) {
    double v = toOptimize(arg);
    if( v > value_ ) {
      value_ = v;
      index_ = arg;
    }
  }

  bool operator<(const MaximumEntryPair& other) const {
    if( value_ < other.value_ ) return true;
    return false;
  }  

  size_t index_;
  double value_;
};



int main() {
  MaximumEntryPair best;
#pragma omp parallel 
  {
    MaximumEntryPair thread_local;
    #pragma omp for
    for(size_t ii = 0 ; ii < 1050 ; ++ii) {
      thread_local.update(ii);
    } // implicit barrier
#pragma omp critical
    {
      if ( best < thread_local ) best = thread_local;
    }

  } // implicit barries
  cout << "The maximum is " << best.value_ << " obtained at index " << best.index_ << std::endl;
  cout << "\t toOptimize(" << best.index_ << ") = " << toOptimize(best.index_) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a separate buffer for each thread to store a `val` and `idx` and then select the max out of the buffer afterwards.

```
    std::vector<double> thread_maxes(omp_get_max_threads());
    std::vector<int>    thread_max_ids(omp_get_max_threads());

    #pragma omp for reduction(max: best_value)
    for(size_t n = 2 ; n <= MAX ; ++n)
    {
      int thread_num = omp_get_num_threads();
      double v = toOptimize(n);
      if(v > thread_maxes[thread_num])
      {
        thread_maxes[thread_num] = v;
        thread_max_ids[thread_num] = i;
      }
    }

    std::vector<double>::iterator max =
      std::max_element(thread_maxes.begin(), thread_maxes.end());
    best.val = *max;
    best.idx = thread_max_ids[max - thread_maxes.begin()];
```

Comment: @Massimiliano Fair enough, but this should drop off as each thread converges on its max value and the amount of accesses to `thread_maxes` and `thread_max_ids` approaches zero.  However this only applies to this specific scenario.

Comment: What I dislike here is that the code wouldn't compile without OpenMP, which is a nice property of most openMP code.

Comment: @PierreBdR Fair enough also, this hasn't ever been an issue for me so I don't think about it much.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fine.  It has O(nthreads) convergence with the critical section.  However, it's possible to do this with O(Log(nthreads)) convergence.

For example imagine there were 32 threads.
You would first find the local max for the 32 threads.  Then you could combine pairs with 16 threads, then 8, then 4, then 2, then 1.  In five steps you could merge the local max values without a critical section and free threads in the process.  But your method would merge the local max values in 32 steps in a critical section and uses all threads.

The same logic goes for a reduction.  That's why it's best to let OpenMP do the reduction rather than do it manually with an atomic section.  But at least in the C/C++ implementation of OpenMP there is no easy way to get the max/min in O(Log(nthreads)).  It might be possible using tasks but I have not tried that.

In practice this might not make a difference since the time to merge the local values even with a critical section is probably negligible compared the time to do the parallel loop.  It probably makes more of a difference on the GPU though where the number of "threads" is much larger.

Comment: I agree, but as you said, the cost is almost none compared to the one of the computation.