# OpenMP argmin reduction for multiple values

Tags: c, openmp

I have a routine that uses a loop to compute the minimum height of a particle given a surface of particles beneath. This routine tries random positions and compute the minimum height and then returns the `x, y, z` values, where `z` is the minimum height found.

This routine can be parallelized with `omp parallel for`. But I am having problems figuring out how to get the triplet `(x, y, z)`, not just the minimum `z` (because the minimum `z` of course corresponds to a given `x, y` coordinates). I can actually get the smallest `z` by using a reduction operation as follows

```
double x = 0, y = 0, z = 1.0e300; // initially z is large
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(min:z)
for(int trial = 0; trial < NTRIALS; ++trial) {
    // long routine that, at the end, computes x, y, z 
    // and selects only the x, y, z corresponding to the 
    // smallest z
}
```

But I cannot get the corresponding `x` and `y`. At the end I just end up with a random `x` and `y` written by one of the threads.

Is it possible to get also those values? How? I was thinking on having an array where each thread stores their value of `x, y, zmin` and then, after the reduction operation, compare each thread `zmin` with the reduced global value and then get those that correspond to the choosing one. Is there a better way in the sense that OpenMP does it so I don't need to define this dynamic array and compare floats?

Comment: What level of OpenMP conformance do you have?  You can write a custom reduction if you have OpenMP 4.0 or newer, I think.  (Obviously you'd need to combine `x`, `y`, and `z` into a single struct to pass to the reduction).

Comment: There are some older questions regarding argmin, but given the three values and outdated answers I am not closing as duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782038/omp-max-reduction-with-storage-of-index https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618258/how-to-implement-argmax-with-openmp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

You can implement an *argmin* for multiple values using user defined reduction (available since OpenMP 4.0). For that you have to put the triple in one type. It is helpful to define a convenience function.

```
struct xyz {
    double x; double y; double z;
}

struct xyz xyz_min2(struct xyz a, struct xyz b) {
    return a.z < b.z ? a : b; 
}

#pragma omp declare reduction(xyz_min: struct xyz: omp_out=xyz_min2(omp_out, omp_in))\
    initializer(omp_priv={0, 0, DBL_MAX})

struct xyz value = {0, 0, DBL_MAX};
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(xyz_min:value)
for (int trial = 0; trial < NTRIALS; ++trial) {
    struct xyz new_value = ...;
    value = xyz_min2(value, new_value);
}
```

Comment: Excellent. This is what I was looking for. I did not know about omp declare reduction. I just had to fix the parallel for since it should read reduction(xyz_min:value). Also, for some reason, I had to use omp_priv={0, 0, DBL_MAX} (only one brace). Thanks again.