# Dependency in OMP analysis

Tags: c, dependencies, openmp

Hi i am new to parallel programming and im struggling with a dependency issue. I have the following function which i would like to make parallel, the aim of the code is to return the next node in a graph which is then to be used for Dijkstra's algorithm in my program.

```
long getNextNode(graph* G)
{
    long i;
    long minD;
    long nextNode;

    nextNode = -1;
    minD = INF;

    //Find unvisited node with lowest Distance to the intial node
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(runtime)
    for(i = 0; i<G->N; i++){
        if( (G->visited[i] == NOT_VISITED) && (G->D[i] < minD) ){
                minD = G->D[i];
                nextNode = i;
        }
    }

    return nextNode;
}
```

The variables look like this:

```
#define INF INT_MAX
typedef struct {
    long N; //Number of nodes
    char** node; //Matrix of Nodes and connections

    int* D; //Result of Dijkstra Algorithm. Shortest path length for each node.
    char* visited; //Used to flag which nodes have been visted yet or not.
} graph;
```

I am struggling to understand where the dependency is? My results from running it sequentially is different from my attempted parallel version above. Could someone show me if possible a way to fix this?

Comment: You're not initializing `minD`, and possibly clobbering `nextNode` (think about what happens when `G->D[i] < minD` is true in two threads, and the one in which `G->D[i]` is lower writes to `minD` first, then the second one writes to it again).  To fix it, you may want to make a thread private variable for the loop, then compare each of those sequentially at the end.  My OpenMP is a bit rusty so I don't remember the exact syntax, but it shouldn't be hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition. That is, two threads could collide and do an incorrect update.

Suppose, we had two threads (e.g. A and B) and they are examining `G->[iA]` (with value 10) and `G->[iB]` (with value 20) respectively. Suppose, these values are *both* less than the value of `minD` which has the value 30.

So, they both want to update `minD` *and* `nextIndex` at the same time. Obviously, thread A has the [ultimately] better value, but there is nothing to prevent A from setting `minD/nextIndex` and *then* B trashing that value.

This is because the `if` test and the set of the new values are not *atomic*. Otherwise, if they were atomic, A would set the shared values and B would *not* because its `if` test would fail [and *not* do the update] because it would be guaranteed to see the values updated by A

---

*Caveat:* I'm *not* an `openmp` guru, so take all of the following with a grain of salt.

This *should* work but may not be super efficient:

```
long
getNextNode(graph * G)
{
    long i;
    long minD;
    long nextNode;

    nextNode = -1;
    minD = INF;

    // Find unvisited node with lowest Distance to the intial node
#pragma omp parallel for shared(minD,nextNode) schedule(runtime)
    for (i = 0; i < G->N; i++) {
        if (G->visited[i] != NOT_VISITED)
            continue;

#pragma omp atomic
        if (G->D[i] < minD) {
            minD = G->D[i];
            nextNode = i;
        }
    }

    return nextNode;
}
```

---

Another way would to add a `reduction` clause but I'm not sure that applies because you have *two* variables.  For example, if you didn't need `nextNode`, to get the minimum value, you'd could do:

```
long
getNextNode(graph * G)
{
    long i;
    long minD;

    minD = INF;

    // Find unvisited node with lowest Distance to the intial node
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(min:minD) schedule(runtime)
    for (i = 0; i < G->N; i++) {
        if (G->visited[i] != NOT_VISITED)
            continue;

        if (G->D[i] < minD)
            minD = G->D[i];
    }

    return minD;
}
```

---

Another way is to let each thread's loop free run with private variables (e.g. `private(nextNode,minD)`) but store the final `nextNode` and `minD` values in a global array, indexed by thread number:

```
struct res {
    long res_node;
    long res_min;
};

struct res thread_list[NUMTHREADS];

thread_list[my_thread_number].res_node = nextNode;
thread_list[my_thread_number].res_min = minD;
```

Then, after exiting the parallel section, traverse the list in the main thread and select the entry with the lowest `res_min` value.

I'm not sure of the exact way to do this under `openmp`, so the above is pseudo-code, but there are examples of how to do this on the web.

---

But, this strikes me as running in `O(n^2)` time. That is, `getNextNode` takes `O(n)` time, but it is [presumably] called `n` times (i.e.) `O(n*n)` or `O(n^2)`.

Assume you have 8 cores, this reduces to `O(n^2)/8`, which is still `O(n^2)`

If *possible*, it might be better to create a sorted list within your `graph` (e.g. add a `long *S` to your graph struct) and pre-sort this based on `visited/D`.

The sort would take `O(n*log2(n))` time.

Then, `getNextNode` could just traverse `S` in order and get the same effect. But, the time becomes `O(n*log2(n)) + O(n)` which reduces to `O(n*log2(n))`

Of course, it depends whether you modify your graph between calls to `getNextNode` or not.

If you *are* able to do this, running single threaded might be the way to go.

Comment: You analysis is correct, but your suggested solutions are problematic. `atomic` doesn't apply to `if`. The res-array solution is affected by false-sharing. Take a look [at user-defined reduction for argmin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52391259/620382).